# Simple open source filter for php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, open-source

I know I could code what I'm trying to achieve, but I'd like to know if such a plugin exists....

This is what im looking for,
A web page which takes a mysql table structure and accepts user conditions for a select.

For example, if a table consists of age,location, name and email, is there a plugin which once set up shows a page where a user can enter conditions for any of/ some the columns he wants and then run a search which displays the records fromt eh mysql database...

conditions like age between or age> 
location in ('..','...')
etc etc...

basically  a simple script to search for a bunch of records based on the users conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don'y know if i understood you correctly and i don't know if this is what you are looking for exactly but this might do.

http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/

Comment: I've seen this before...
Im kind of looking for something which will help a person who doesnt know a word of sql type in values into text boxes and use these to frame the where clause of the query...
It should support ands ors and allow the user to choose which fields he wants to search by etc.

Comment: I am also looking for a more filter based solution. I want it to do and/ors in searches. I do not see that this plugin is able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I use phpMyAdmin - you can browse your tables, insert data, run open-ended queries or use a search form to fill in what you're looking for.  Plus loads more.  It's excellent, free and (I believe) open source.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/

Comment: Yes i know phpmyadmin does the job, but i want to integrate it with my project, and i was looking for a simple plugin.